# What is the best way to load a lot of Overlays to a MapView in Android?

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

I want to load a lot of Overlays into one MapView.

Say i want to load about 10.000 or more Overlays to the Globe.

What is the best way to do that? I understand that with a MapView loading 10k of drawables at maximum zoom out will propably not work. (Both stability and user-experience).

So is there any workaround to do that. All suggestions are welcome.

Maybe creating stacks of Overlays, don't allow max zoom out, Overlays to come with the map as a picture and not be rendered in Android etc etc. Don't know if all of that are possible.

I could use some guidance here.

Comment: Question: 10,000s of overlays or 10,000s of items on some overlays.

Comment: @weakwire To Harald question, do you mean 10,000 markers in some overlays or do you have 10,000 overlays to add? Can you cleared up the use cases?

Comment: I have many overlays i guess. I don't quite understand having many markers in one overlay,but if it's a viable solution i could try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a self Clustering Solution. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7447350/android-maps-point-clustering) you can see it. Groups the geopoints if the projection of them in the mapView is too close. Also renders only the visible poins

Answer (score 2):

[This Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545996/android-maps-asynchronous-loading-of-overlay-items) might prove useful. The first responder recommends doing it as an async task, which could load from a SQL db. I'm not sure what kind of performance implications 10 000 overlays would have, but you could tweak the async task to space out loads in the background.

Hope that helps.